# how to reset the content by switching to an other tab - iOS?

Tags: ios, tabs, touch, tabbar

I got a tabbed iOS-app. So i got 3 ViewControllers.
If switch from the 1st to the 2nd tab - i want to reset the content of the first tab !
Someone an idea ?
The other idea to solve the problem is to disable the tabicons while a touch is active in the content.

Pls Guys help.

Comment: Does each tab have just one view controller? Or do they point to navigation controllers?

Comment: there are only one view controller for each - so no navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reset the content in `-viewWillDisappear:`